# Is it possible to display a modal in javascript like a popover below?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried to display the modal in bootstrap like in the popover below and does not work
Is it possible to have it fixed and work well?

```
.on('click', '.event', function () {
        var $t = $(this), 
            index = +($t.attr('data-index')), 
            haspop = $t.data('popover'),
            data, time;

        if (haspop || isNaN(index)) { return true; }
        data = options.data[index];
        time = data.start.toTimeString();
        if (time && data.end) { time = time + ' - ' + data.end.toTimeString(); }
        $t.data('popover',true);
        $t.popover({content: '<p><strong>' + time + '</strong></p>'+data.text, html: true, placement: 'auto left'}).popover('toggle');
        return false;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

A modal is compsited with two elements.  One is the dialog and the other one is the backdrop. So you want the popover has a backdrop, right?

Write a function to create popover.

Implements the logic that creating and showing a backdrop first and then creating the popover element.